A movie that the main ghost 'stuffed' people alive
It is a movie that I watched once a few years ago with my dad and can't remember the name.
The main antagonist turns out to be a man that was killing people by stuffing them alive
I don't remember much about the film and my explination sucks... really... Though I do remember that it was in a farm-like place and some of the characters consisted of two women-sisters- and a girl. Cant remember a man but was pretty sure there was one.
Also remember that seeing ghosts was in something in the family of the women, The sister(aunt) accepted, the woman denied it, and the woman's daughter had it but was confused.
Again I apologize if it sucks, but it is really all that I remember, and I really miss the film

A little light on details but I'll take a stab at 
The Haunting in Connecticut 2: Ghosts of Georgia
It includes a scene as below which may be what you are thinking of
Its set in a farm in Georgia, and consists of a number of sisters and a girl so I think it fits quite well.
The ghost (The station master) begins to kill one of the women in the film by her choking up needles and stitching as he was a Taxidermist"
Please see the below links for more information.
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1457765/?ref_=fn_al_tt_4



